# Objects blend into the background

Tags: objects

I can't figure out how to change this or what I clicked to cause it but the object completely disappears if it's not highlighted

[image]

Comment: Blender doesn't work fine with the latest AMD driver, so eithr switch to the previous one or try Properties panel > Render > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling, I had an older version and I didn't realize that 2.9 was out